# power query conditional adding up, with different columns

Tags: conditional-statements, powerquery, sumifs

I need direction or exact formula help in power query. I am trying to calculate the sum of columns if condition is true, and bringing the result in new column. The code is Below;

```
({If [Num] = 1 Then  Sum([Column1](Value),[Column3](Value)}),
```

If Column(Num) equlas 1 then add values in column1 and 3
If Column(Num) = 2 then add values in column2 and column3
Maybe I need to use GroupBy...

In brief what I want to do is use sumif in excel

[image]

Comment: You are trying to sum all column or just a few of then ? And under what condition?  For example sum all other columns when column3=1;  sum column12 when (column3=1 or column12=1)

Comment: Sum column12 and column9 if Column3 is equal to 1

Comment: Please show example of data input and desired output. It is not clear if you want to sum just the value on a given row (`=if [Column3] = 1 then [Column9] + [Column12] else null`), a running conditional total, fill every cell in the column with the conditional total, or exactly what.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Look above I have added similar visual, and changed the question. In brief, I want to use SumIf of Excel in PowerQuery

Comment: I don't see your desired output.

Comment: To sumu the values in column 1 and 3 if num(column) equals 1

Comment: Just the values in the same row?

Comment: See if my posted answer is what yo want.  It sums the values in the same **ROW** depending on the value in another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your original question and the comments, it appears you only want to add the numbers in the same row under certain conditions of column 3 (or Num in your revised question).

Try:

```
=if [Column3] = 1 then [Column9] + [Column12] else null
```

or, in native M-Code:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "New Column Name", each if [Column3] = 1 then [Column9] + [Column12] else null)
```